# 'fwupdmgr update' exit with 1 (error)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, firmware, fwupdmgr

I run `LinuxMint21` and when I run `fwupdmgr update`, it exit with 1 (error). But there's no error on `STDERR`. Any clue?

My system is up to date.

```
$ uname -a
Linux box 5.15.0-67-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:14:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# tree /boot/efi/
/boot/efi/
└── EFI
    ├── BOOT
    │   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
    │   ├── fbx64.efi
    │   └── mmx64.efi
    ├── debian
    │   ├── BOOTX64.CSV
    │   ├── fbx64.efi
    │   ├── grub.cfg
    │   ├── grubx64.efi
    │   ├── mmx64.efi
    │   └── shimx64.efi
    └── ubuntu
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── fw
        │   └── fwupd-0123456789abcdef.cap
        ├── fwupdx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi

5 directories, 16 files
```

and

```
# fwupdmgr update
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • MZVLB512HBJQ-000L7
 • System Firmware
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Upgrade UEFI dbx from 77 to 217?                                             ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ This updates the dbx to the latest release from Microsoft which adds         ║
║ insecure versions of grub and shim to the list of forbidden signatures due   ║
║ to multiple discovered security updates.                                     ║
║                                                                              ║
║ Before installing the update, fwupd will check for any affected executables  ║
║ in the ESP and will refuse to update if it finds any boot binaries signed    ║
║ with any of the forbidden signatures.If the installation fails, you will     ║
║ need to update shim and grub packages before the update can be deployed.     ║
║                                                                              ║
║ Once you have installed this dbx update, any DVD or USB installer images     ║
║ signed with the old signatures may not work correctly.You may have to        ║
║ temporarily turn off secure boot when using recovery or installation media,  ║
║ if new images have not been made available by your distribution.             ║
║                                                                              ║
║ UEFI dbx and all connected devices may not be usable while updating.         ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Perform operation? [Y|n]: 
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Restarting device…       [***************************************]
Writing…                 [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date: /boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi Authenticode checksum [0123456789abcdef] is present in dbx
```

And:

```
# fwupdmgr --version
runtime   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9
runtime   com.dell.libsmbios            2.4
compile   org.freedesktop.gusb          0.3.10
runtime   org.kernel                    5.15.0-67-generic
compile   com.hughsie.libjcat           0.1.9
compile   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9
runtime   org.freedesktop.gusb          0.3.10
```

The error is there:

```
# fwupdmgr get-upgrades
│
└─UEFI dbx:
  │   Device ID:          0123456789abcdef
  │   Summary:            UEFI revocation database
  │   Current version:    77
  │   Minimum Version:    77
  │   Vendor:             UEFI:Linux Foundation
  │   Install Duration:   1 second
  │   Update State:       Transient failure
  │   Update Error:       Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date: /boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi Authenticode checksum [0123456789abcdef] is present in dbx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date: /boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi

It's telling you that you have an old version of `shimx64.efi` which would now get blacklisted in this Secure Boot revocation database update. In other words, if the update was installed, you might have to disable Secure Boot to allow your Debian installation to boot.

But if `/boot/efi/EFI/debian` is not in use (e.g. if you have replaced Debian with Mint, and this directory is just a last remnant of the old installation of Debian), you could just remove the `/boot/efi/EFI/debian` directory, and then `fwupdmgr update` could proceed without errors.

The `fwupdmgr` command is not smart enough to figure out if the `/boot/efi/EFI/debian` directory remains there intentionally, or if it's just a remnant of an old, overwritten installation, so it stops the update process in order to be maximally safe.

Since Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, it has a complete set of boot files of its own in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. So deleting the `/boot/efi/EFI/debian` directory should have no effect at all on your Mint installation.

However, if you wish to be extra sure, you should run `sudo efibootmgr -v` and verify that the boot entry whose number is identified by the `BootCurrent:` line is actually the one that refers to the `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`, not to `\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi`. If the `sudo efibootmgr -v` output includes a reference to Debian and you wish to remove it, you can do it with the `efibootmgr` command; see its man page for examples.

This UEFI dbx (= Secure Boot revocation list) update is related to the [BootHole vulnerability of July 2020](https://eclypsium.com/2020/07/29/theres-a-hole-in-the-boot/) and the related group of vulnerabilities discovered in its aftermath. By now, all distributions have long since replaced any vulnerable bootloader components as necessary, and the [UEFI Forum has now published an updated revocation list](https://uefi.org/revocationlistfile) that will prevent the vulnerable bootloader versions from running.